# Unknown error with running the nosetests from Learning Python the Hard Way Ex46

Tags: python, automated-tests

I am working on [ex46](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html) from Learning Python the Hard way.

I first created tests/NAME_tests.py as the following:

```
from nose.tools import *
import NAME

def setup():
    print "SETUP!"

def teardown():
    print "TEAR DOWN!"

def test_basic():
    print "I RAN!"
```

And then I ran `~/projects/skeleton $ nosetests`

However, I am getting the following error and I have no idea why there is a missing parenthesis.

```
    print "SETUP!"
                 ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are using *Python 3.4* as can be seen from the paths in the screenshot.

In Python 3.x , `print` is a function, not a statement. You should use it as a function. Example -

```
print("SETUP!")
```

Similarly for all prints .

The Example in [ex46](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html) is most probably written for Python 2 (In which `print` was a statement) .

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in Python 3, you need to add parentheses around the value to be printed. So it should be `print ('SETUP!')`